How to pass parameters through the Initialize method of a MonoBehaviour class?
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Initialize(Vector3 spawnPosition, InputManager inputManager)
    {
        _playerMovement = new PlayerMovement(_inputManager, _rigidbody, _wheels);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _playerMovement.Method();
    }
}

I want to make it possible to create a player in Bootstrap and immediately pass parameters to it (Vector3 spawnPosition, InputManager inputManager).
The problem is that I need to Instantiate it first and then call Initialize, but during this time FixedUpdate may be called, which will try to access null _playerMovement, causing errors.
There are 2 ways to solve this problem:

Check _playerMovement for null in FixedUpdate, but I'd rather avoid extra if statements in Update.
Make Player without MonoBehaviour, but it's too long and there may be simpler ways.


"but I'd rather avoid extra if statements in Update.". OK, but why? "Make Player without MonoBehaviour, but it's too long and there may be simpler ways." Is this really an option? Sounds like a design issue. What does the InputManager do? Is it a singleton? What class type is PlayerMovement derived from?

@TheNomad Avoiding if statements in Update is just my preference. Doing it once isn't a big deal, but if there are many cases like that, it might affect optimization.
InputManager is not a MonoBehaviour class; it's created in Bootstrap. It has Vertical and Horizontal variables set from the UIController class. In UIController, I create buttons and bind events for pressing.

@TheNomad PlayerMovement is a standalone class responsible for variables like speed and controlling an array of wheels (Player being the vehicle).

OK so for short, InputManger is your handler for the new input system. I assume it implements IInputManager then? Is it a singleton? As you didn't answer that. As for PlayerMovement, I assume it is derived from System.Object, not UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour, right? As for if statements in Update(), trust me, that won't be your bottleneck. Besides, there are methods to tell the engine to not call FixedUpdate() if you really are that worried (but trust me, that if should be the least of your worries).

InputManager is not a singleton, and it does not implement the IInputManager interface. PlayerMovement derives from System.Object. The methods that inform Unity not to call FixedUpdate() work in a way that it won't be called at all until I explicitly allow it?

Yes and sort of no, meaning it applies to more engine events, not just FixedUpdate(). But the idea behind your if worries is you want to make sure the variable is assigned, right? So that should cover that requirement, but as I said, it's a bit overkill. The *Update() calls should be called after the initialization calls anyway. So I think your worry might be a non-issue, but this all depends on the design of your game, which is why I said the real problem might be a design issue. I'll try a PoC and reply tomorrow if I have optimal results for you, as it's late now and need to sleep.

The problem is that I need to Instantiate it first and then call Initialize, but during this time FixedUpdate may be called ... no, why should it? You would call var newInstance = Instantiate(...); newInstance.Initialize() .... FixedUpdate would never be called between these two lines ...

@derHugo i thought this is unsafe to use this code, cuz FixedUpdate might accidentally  called, but thanks

As far as I know theres no other way to do it except for checking if _playerMovement null.
This is an easy way to do a null check without having to put an if statement in your FixedUpdate.
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    _playerMovement?.Method();
}

And if you don't like that way you could also call the method in another function.
private void PlayerMovementMethod()
{
    if (_playerMovement != null)
        _playerMovement.Method();
    // or you can use:
    // _playerMovement?.Method();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    PlayerMovementMethod();
}


Does the internal implementation of _playerMovement?.Method(); work the same as if (_playerMovement != null), or is it different in some way?

@WasTabon There are no differences, just _playerMovement?.Method(); is more concise.

@WasTabon The if is still executed every frame though. So there is really no difference. Actually, if you are worried about optimizations, consider the second scenario adds an extra call on the instruction stack. So it's not better. Again, the rapport is to your worries regarding any overhead. As I told you, it's not that much and it's better off in FixedUpdate() directly. Optimization should only be done after profiling, not before.
